# Replacing a string of text when only knowing a certain amount of characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of PO numbers. They look something like (4010059877-TUR36036133 or TUR6039716## 4010073239). I need to be able to narrow the cell down to only the PO number which is the 4010059877 number. The only consistent part about the part I want to exclude is the "TUR########".

I have worked on code that excludes all non-numeric characters, but some of the cells have these "TUR #'s". I worked on a find and replace with a wildcard "*".  I have also searched the web and didn't see anything similar.

Find and Replace attempted code

```
Sub Replace()

    Columns("AJ").Replace What:="TUR*", _
                          Replacement:="", _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, _
                          ReplaceFormat:=False 
End Sub
```

Replacing all non-numeric characters which leaves behind unwanted numbers behind the TUR########

```
Dim finRow As String
finRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A20000").End(xlUp).Row

Set myRange = Sheets("Data").Range("AK2:AK" & finRow)
For Each myCell In myRange
    LastString = ""
    For I = 1 To Len(myCell.Value)
        mT = Mid(myCell.Value, I, 1)
        If mT Like "[0-9]" Then
            tString = mT
        Else
            tString = ""
        End If
        LastString = LastString & tString
    Next I
    myCell.Value = LastString
Next
```

My expected result would be for the TUR######## to be eliminated and replaced with nothing.

Comment: There has to be something between the "TUR" bit and the number you want.

Comment: There is a space about half of the time. The other half there is a dash (-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use InStr() function and then use that to support Left, such that:

```
loc = instr(mycell,"TUR")
val = left(mycell.value,loc-1)
```

---

**Edit1:**

Due to SJR's comment, will add an example of handling the issue when "TUR" is found in position 1:

```
loc = instr(mycell,"TUR")
if loc = 1 then
    val = ""
else
    val = left(mycell.value,loc-1)    
end if
```

---

**Edit2:**

```
Dim val as long 'assumes you will only have a number in the end
val = right(left(mycell.value,12),11)
mycell.value = val
```

This should cut the first parenthesis off and have no issues with the info after the 11 digit PO.  This could even be specific to the case (a switch) where instr(mycell.value,"TUR") is true, in case you have other possible scenarios.

Comment: I'm not sure but the second example suggests TUR can be at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @SJR very true.  i will also say that i didn't account for the parenthesis that were listed in the original post.  This was an example of how to use InStr() and Left() to support the inquiry.  I will go stand on the limb that OP indicated POcode-TURcode is standard format and TUR wouldn't be in position 1!

Comment: @Cyril how would one adjust this to work with column AK? I keep getting Compile Error: Function call on left hand side of assignment must return variant or object. I tried to insert `Dim Loc As Integer`  as well as `Dim Val As Integer`. I then get an object required error. I also tried to go off of the same theory as the above string removing all non numeric integers.

Comment: @MattLane loc is fine as long, though I would be careful about the use of val as a number until you've removed the parenthesis.  I would guess that the error, once you have declared the variables, would be that *loc = instr(mycell.value,"TUR") didn't have .value in my example.

Comment: @MattLane Regarding the additional characters, I'll give you one more thing as an option, which I'll update my post... should be easier with all of the parenthesis and whatnot, assuming they are consistent.

Comment: Anywho who is reading this, I chose not to do *mycell.value = right(left(mycell.value,12),11)** due to having seen error on different user's computers where I resolved that issue by declaring a variable first (val in this scenario).

Answer (score 0):

We can also try doing a regex replacement:

```
Dim Regex As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
Dim input As String = "4010059877-TUR36036133"
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace(input, "([0-9]+)-TUR[0-9]+", "$1")
Console.WriteLine(output)
```

This outputs: `4010059877`

Comment: Will need a bit of tweaking for Excel VBA.

Comment: @SJR I'm afraid I only have access to a Visual Basic tester at the moment :-(